# Are $\pi$ and $\ln(2)$ linearly independent over rational numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Are $\pi$ and $\ln(2)$ linearly independent over rational numbers? Are there any proofs either way, or partial results?

Comment: @Cursed1701 I for one think it's a perfectly good question

Comment: Algebraically independent? Linearly independent?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, $\{\pi,\ln(2)\}$ is linearly independent over $\mathbb Q$, because if $r\pi = s\ln(2)$ were true for rational $r$ and $s$, then $e^\pi = 2^{s/r}$ would be algebraic, [but it isn't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%27s_constant).

Comment: Doesn't "algebraic over the rationals" allow for expressions of the form $r\pi=s\mathrm{ln}(2)+t$ where $t$ is also rational?

Comment: @Oscar: You put in quotes "algebraic over the rationals" but I don't know what you're quoting.  I interpreted the question as asking whether  $\{\pi,\ln(2)\}$ is a linearly independent set in $\mathbb R$ as a $\mathbb Q$-vector space. You are saying you would interpret it as linear independence of $\{\pi,\ln(2),1\}$? On the other hand, if algebraic independence was desired then it's much more than you say.

Comment: @OscarCunningham $\pi, \ln{2}$ are independent as vectors over $\mathbb{Q}$ iff $\frac{\ln{2}}{\pi}$ is rational, but as Jonas said, it cannot be.