# Sum of two particular irrationals is irrational

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, transcendental-numbers

I am trying to show that a rational number say, $Q$, plus two specific irrational numbers, $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\ln(2)$, will produce an irrational number.

I realize that if I can show $\frac{\pi}{4} \pm \ln(2)$ is irrational then $Q$ plus that result will also be irrational.

I am feeling stuck because I know the irrationals aren't closed under addition and I don't think $\frac{\pi}{4} \pm \ln(2)$ will produce a rational, but how can I rigorously show this?

My question explicitly is:
Does a rational number $Q + \frac{\pi}{4} + \ln(2)$ produces a rational number and does 
Q + $\frac{\pi}{4} - \ln(2)$ produces a rational number?

Comment: The presence of $Q$ here is irrelevant. The question is whether $\pi/4\pm\ln 2$ is rational or irrational. Although we all have a hunch, this is a hard problem to settle definitively.

Comment: Perhaps with a bit of fiddling, you can use the [Gelfond-Schneider Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gelfond%E2%80%93Schneider_theorem) to settle this, but this seems very strange for what I assume is an elementary mathematics course.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am an undergrad working on a proof that I recently saw and I ran into this issue and was not sure how to handle it. The question is not from any particular course.

Comment: Ah, well, I'm not sure if Gelfond-Schneider works, but read about it and happy playing!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219302/are-pi-and-ln2-linearly-independent-over-rational-numbers/2219330

Comment: The above link may be helpful, but it is the linear independence of $\pi$ and $\ln2$. We need the linear independence of $\pi$, $\ln 2$, and $1$ over rational numbers.

Comment: Could you explain why we need to include independence of 1? Is this because that would show that they are algebraically independent?

Comment: That was to make a linear combination of those over rational numbers.

Comment: You may find these links helpful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118523/is-pi-log-ab-for-some-integers-a-b-1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119/how-find-this-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac13n13n23n3?rq=1

Comment: Especially, this paper which was mentioned in the first link: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/tij.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Transcendence of $\pi/4\pm \log2$**

It is possible to answer your question from this paper that I linked: http://www.math.tifr.res.in/~saradha/tij.pdf

> Theorem 1: 
>   If $T$ is defined by
>   $$
> T=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(\alpha n + \beta)}{(qn+s_1)(qn+s_2)}
> $$
>   where $\alpha, \beta \in \overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $s_1, s_2\in\mathbb{Z}$, $|\alpha|+|\beta|>0$, and the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_{2q}$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$, $qn+s_1$, $qn+s_2$ do not vanish when $n\geq 0$, and assume $\alpha\neq 0$ if $s_1\equiv s_2$ mod $q$. Then $T$ is transcendental.

We apply the theorem for $\pi/4\pm \log 2$. Note that from Taylor series, 
$$
\pi/4= 1-\frac13+\frac15-+\cdots, \ \ \log2=  1 - \frac12 + \frac13 -+ \cdots,
$$
Thus, 
$$
\pi/4+\log 2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\frac1{2n+1} + \frac1{n+1} \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \frac{6n+4}{(2n+1)(2n+2)},
$$
$$
\pi/4-\log 2 = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n \left(\frac1{2n+1} - \frac1{n+1} \right)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{-2n}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}.
$$

Therefore, by Theorem 1, the numbers $\pi/4\pm \log 2$ are transcendental, hence irrational.

**Addendum**

By applying Theorem 2 of the paper and [How find this sum $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/573119/how-find-this-sum-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac13n13n23n3?noredirect=1&lq=1), we obtain that 
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)}=\frac14\left(\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 3} - \log 3\right)
$$
is transcendental.

**A General Result**

As @Ted Shifrin notes, a general result of this sort can be proved by Baker's theorem (which is a generalization of Gelfond-Schneider):

> [Baker's Theorem]
>
> If $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ are algebraic numbers, not $0$ or $1$. If $\log\alpha_1, \ldots, \log\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $1, \log\alpha_1, \ldots, \log\alpha_n$ are linearly independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Using $\log(-1)=i\pi$ and the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic), we see that $\log(-1), \log 2, \log 3$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thus, by Baker's theorem, $1, \log(-1), \log 2, \log 3$ are linearly independent over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. This implies that if $\beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3$ are algebraic and not all zero, then 
$$
\beta_1 \pi+\beta_2 \log 2 + \beta_3 \log 3
$$
is transcendental.

Comment: Could you please explain what the notation of the Q with the bar on top means? Does that mean the irrationals? Sorry for such a trivial question. I have not seen this notation before.

Comment: $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ means the set of all algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$. This includes numbers such as $\sqrt 2, \sqrt[3] 2, \ldots$, but not the numbers such as $e, \pi, \log 2, \ldots$.