# Linear Dependence of $\{1,\ln(2), \pi\}$ over the rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I have seen the proof that $\{\ln(2),\pi\}$ is linearly independent

Found here:

[Are $\pi$ and $\ln(2)$ linearly independent over rational numbers?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2219302/are-pi-and-ln2-linearly-independent-over-rational-numbers)

However, when trying to show that $\{\ln(2), \pi, 1\}$ is linearly independent (or dependent) I am having some trouble.

Here was my attempt:
Suppose that $\{\ln(2), \pi, 1\}$ is linearly dependent then For $a,b,c$ be elements of $Q$ such that $a,b,c$ are non-zero.

$$a + b\ln(2) + c\pi = 0$$

$$e^{a+c\pi}(2^b) = 1$$

Once I got to this point I am feeling shaky about the $e^{a+c\pi}$. I realize that this is very close to Gelfond's Constant $(e^\pi)$, but I have tried to do some gymnastics with the algebra and I can't quite get it to a form where I recognize that this is transcendental (hence irrational). A point in the right direction would be highly appreciated!

Comment: This follows from Baker's theorem. See my answer to your previous question about $\pi/4 \pm \ln 2$.

Comment: @i707107 : Neither stating Baker's theorem nor linking to anything about it seems rather odd in this context. Here's a link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thank you for the link. I wanted to remind him that I mentioned Baker's theorem in the answer to a former question.

Comment: More interestingly, can we show that no (rational) linear combination of pi and ln(2) is rational?

Comment: Not sure of this being complete, but integrals of the form $\int_0^1 \frac{x^m(1-x)^n}{1+x^2}dx$ yield results of the form $a+b\log(2)+c\pi$
That integrand is small but not zero, thus making $a+b\log(2)+c\pi=0$ impossible.

Comment: Any nontrivial linear combination of $\pi$ and $\ln 2$ over algebraic numbers is transcendental. i.e. $a\pi + b\ln 2$ is transcendental for any algebraic $a$, $b$, not all zero.

Comment: @i707107 you have proven to be my hero time and time again. Thank you!